# What does this type of const function expression do?

Tags: typescript

I am having difficulties understanding what this line of code does/achieves. I don't understand the syntax and can't really find anything helpful on Google.

```
const uniqueId = (prefix?: string | undefined) => prefix};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const uniqueId = (prefix?: string | undefined) => prefix};
```

it is a TypeScript syntax. And it means that that function can receive zero or one argument and that argument should be either string type or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

- `const` means the variable is forced to stay as `(prefix?: string | undefined) => prefix};`.
- `uniqueId` is the name of the constant variable.
- The "prefix" in
  `(prefix?: string | undefined) => prefix};` is the name of the
  argument.
- `?: string | undefined` means the argument is expected/must
  be a string, or undefined.
- `=> prefix` means it should just return
  the prefix immediately, which is just the rules of arrow functions.

Please note that the function is invalid, as the end has a `}`, but there is no starting `{`.

**Edit**:

Credit to @Dymtro Huz for this: The `?` in the `prefix?: string` means that the parameter is not required/needed to call the function.

Comment: please, add also that `?` means that the argument is not necessarily required.